# node js returning Syntax error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js

I downloaded and installed `node.js` on Windows and I'm following a simple tutorial from [nodebeginner.org](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#javascript-and-nodejs).

I've created a file called `HelloWorld.js` which contains just:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

When I type `node HelloWorld.js` in the `node.js` console I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I checked my classpath variable and it has the `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` on it.

`HelloWorld.js` is still open in `Notepad++` for editing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share code that you have tried so we can figure out error easily

Comment: thanks, I don't have much just one js file called HelloWorld.js with this line in it `console.log("Hello World");`at the moment, nothing else. The file sits in the Desktop directory. This is what's in the console at the moment:
`> node HelloWorld.js
node HelloWorld.js
     ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

>`

Comment: try typing node and once the console opens just type require("./HelloWorld.js"). See if you get the error again

Answer (score 9):

I think you are already in the the console.

Just follow the steps to fix the error:

1) Try doing `CTRL + C` couple of times. See if you exit the console

2) Then do `node HelloWorld.js`

I think you will get your output

When in your node console already, you can simply do `require("./HelloWorld.js")` to get the output. (Given that you are in the directory that contains this file)

Comment: Yes I was in the console already, but I accessed it by clicking on the nodeje icon application. I closed that, opened the normal windows console, cd'd to the node directory `C:\Program Files\nodejs>node` and then typed `node HelloWorld.js` from there, but I still got the same result, the syntax error. I've CTRL + C to come out of nodejs (but still in the window console) and run node HelloWorld.js from there, expecting to get a different error (in fact I got `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\HelloWorld.js'`)

Comment: No you need to cd to your file directory and not the place where node is installed

Comment: sorry to add to it, no the script file as mentioned is on the desktop while the nodejs application is in C:\Program Files\nodejs\. Do I have to move my HelloWorld.js to the nodejs directory?

Comment: No you do not need to move your file. Just cd to your file directory. For example if your file is in 'hello' folder on the desktop, you simply need to cd Desktop/hello and then do node HelloWorld.js

Comment: OK, I now cd'd to my desktop where the HelloWorld.js file sits but if I type 'node' in the prompt I get another error: `C:\Users\antoniob\Desktop>node
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\antoniob\Desktop>`

Comment: I think you need to set the environment variable for node to make it accessible everywhere if on windows

Comment: As far as I know the environment var is already set, because when I open the path variable, among the other things, it contains this `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

Comment: Right, it looks like I got it to work. I haven't done anything new though, it's just working right now, so I can run the node command from anywhere now (I haven't changed my path variable as it already had nodejs in it).

Answer (score 3):

A little late but I figured this out as I'm learning it as well.  You are not in the correct Node.js command window:

[image]

You are probably trying to run Node.js, ie. the one with the red arrow.  This gives you the "Unexpected identifier" error.  You want the Node.js command prompt, or the one shown with a green arrow.

Craig

Answer (score 2):

> When I type node HelloWorld.js in the node.js console I get

You should type *JavaScript* into the Node.js console.

`node` is a program name. `HelloWorld.js` is a command line argument. They are not JavaScript.

You should type those into your *shell* (e.g. Windows Powershell or bash).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when following an online course, my mistake was that i did not safe the file i was following as .js in the name when saving.
Therefore my Hello.js did not open because it was only Hello

Answer (score 0):

If people are facing below-mentioned error:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at the time of running, `console.log("Hello World");` code with command, `node HelloWorld.js`, in VS code editor

Problem :

> node HelloWorld.js      ^^^^^  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Solution :

(1)  Just install `Babel JavaScript` extension in VS code editor

(2)  After `Babel JavaScript` extension is installed, save your Program and then run your program with the command, `node HelloWorld.js`

Definitely will get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on linux and I'd the same issue
what I was writing in terminal is :

1. node
2. node file.js
   all what I had to do is to write node file.js from the start  without writing node first .

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old, I just solved it. So for anyone who still likes an answer: Apparently Node.Js installs two different consoles or executables. There is "Node.js" and there is "Node.js command prompt". Use the latter and it will work

To clarify, I used [another tutorial](https://kinsta.com/nl/kennisbank/wat-is-node-js) in Dutch. Use the Javascript code in there and then in your web browser type `http://localhost:3000`. There you will see the Hello World output.

Comment: To clarify: I used another tutorial in Dutch on https://kinsta.com/nl/kennisbank/wat-is-node-js/. Use the Javascript code in there and then in your web browser type: "http: // localhost:3000". There you will see the Hello world output

Answer (score -1):

On windows hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to exit REPL and then run `HelloWorld.js` again